# React > expo > Axio > Async do not wait for response

Tags: reactjs, expo

I am a real dummy on expo and react.
I am trying to fetch infos API using AXIO.

My problem is that before the API request is finish, expo is asking for a return statement.

Here is my code :

```
const sendGetRequest = async () => {
  try {
      const resp = await axios.get(uri, {
        auth: {
        username: '*****',
        password: '****'
      }})
      console.log(resp.data);
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Action</Text>
          <View style={styles.separator} lightColor="#eee" darkColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.1)" />
          <Text>
              Order ID: {resp.data.id}
              Nom client: {resp.data.billing.first_name} {resp.data.billing.last_name}
            </Text>
          <EditScreenInfo path="/screens/TabTwoScreen.tsx" />
        </View>
      );

      

  } catch (err) {
      // Handle Error Here
      console.error(err);
  }
};

sendGetRequest();
```

ANd I get this error :

" Nothing was return from render "

I guess that the await is not really awaiting the result of the async..

Can you help me to see where is my mistake???

Thanks you so much..

Regards,

Pierre

Answer (score 0):

Pierre, try to add await before calling sendGetRequest(); 
Like this:

```
await sendGetRequest();
```

Comment: Hello Insomniacoffee,

Comment: Hello InsomniaCoffee,
Nope... This make the following error:
"'await' is only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules."

Comment: I also tried : 
const setData = async () => { const dataToSet = await sendGetRequest(); }
console.log(setData);
And the result is :
Promise {
  "_U": 0,
  "_V": 0,
  "_W": null,
  "_X": null,
}

Answer (score 0):

ok I found the solution to my problem.
I spent couple of usefull minutes to read more about promises and callbacks.
I was wrong thinking that a promise will hold the code until it get a response. When u understand that a promise send a callback once realized the right code is as following :

```
        // Creating a "DOM listener" -> sorry about vocabulary
        const [myText, setMyText] = useState("My Original Text");
    
        // Creating the async/awaiting function
        const sendGetRequest = async () => {
      try {
          var resp = await axios.get(uri, {
            auth: {
            username: '*******',
            password: '*******'
          }});
          await setMyText('Nom du client:'+ resp.data.billing.first_name);
    
      } catch (err) {
          // Handle Error Here
          console.error(err);
      }
    };
    
    sendGetRequest();

// AND RETURN THE HTML AS FOLLOW
        <View>
            <Text onPress = {() => setMyText("My Changed Text")}>
                    {myText}
            </Text>
        </View>
```

Comment: And I believe, that there is no need to put the asnc request into a function..